# R: how to convert a data frame to an assymetric matrix with an empty corner

Tags: r, matrix

I have the following data frame:

```
table <- data.frame(pop_1 = c("AL","AL","AL","AL","AL","AL","AL","ALT","ALT","ALT","ALT","ALT","ALT","BU","BU","BU","BU","BU","IRK","IRK","IRK","IRK","KK","KK","KK","KYA","KYA","TU"),
                    pop_2 = c("ALT","BU","IRK","KK","KYA","TU","ZAB","BU","IRK","KK","KYA","TU","ZAB","IRK","KK","KYA","TU","ZAB","KK","KYA","TU","ZAB","KYA","TU","ZAB","TU","ZAB","ZAB"),
                    value = c(0.43447,0.15267,0.25912,0.10435,0.19238,0.19186,0.18155,0.34969,0.07506,0.29206,0.13597,0.46354,0.17870,0.18658,0.02297,0.08851,0.18950,0.05176,0.12086,0.02690,0.29669,0.05551,0.04910,0.15779,0.03276,0.23422,0.00568,0.22181))
```

How to convert it to an asymmetric matrix with empty (or NA, etc.) cells like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minor change to your data frame, extra "AL", "AL", "NA" combination at the start. You'll want to do the same for an extra "ZAB" at the end:

```
df<- data.frame(pop_1 = c("AL","AL","AL","AL","AL","AL","AL","AL","ALT","ALT","ALT","ALT","ALT","ALT","BU","BU","BU","BU","BU","IRK","IRK","IRK","IRK","KK","KK","KK","KYA","KYA","TU"),
              pop_2 = c("AL","ALT","BU","IRK","KK","KYA","TU","ZAB","BU","IRK","KK","KYA","TU","ZAB","IRK","KK","KYA","TU","ZAB","KK","KYA","TU","ZAB","KYA","TU","ZAB","TU","ZAB","ZAB"),
              value = c(NA,0.43447,0.15267,0.25912,0.10435,0.19238,0.19186,0.18155,0.34969,0.07506,0.29206,0.13597,0.46354,0.17870,0.18658,0.02297,0.08851,0.18950,0.05176,0.12086,0.02690,0.29669,0.05551,0.04910,0.15779,0.03276,0.23422,0.00568,0.22181))

library(tidyverse)
pivot_wider(df, names_from=pop_1, values_from=value)

 pop_2     AL     ALT      BU     IRK      KK      KYA     TU
  <chr>  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>
1 AL    NA     NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       NA    
2 ALT    0.434 NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       NA    
3 BU     0.153  0.350  NA      NA      NA      NA       NA    
4 IRK    0.259  0.0751  0.187  NA      NA      NA       NA    
5 KK     0.104  0.292   0.0230  0.121  NA      NA       NA    
6 KYA    0.192  0.136   0.0885  0.0269  0.0491 NA       NA    
7 TU     0.192  0.464   0.190   0.297   0.158   0.234   NA    
8 ZAB    0.182  0.179   0.0518  0.0555  0.0328  0.00568  0.222
```

edit:

```
df2 <- df #copy data
names(df2) <- c("pop_2", "pop_1", "value") #re-name copied data
x <- rbind(df, df2) %>% 
              pivot_wider(names_from=pop_1, values_from=value) %>% 
              arrange(pop_2) # sort the columns by alpha
x[upper.tri(x)] <- NA #fill the upper triangle with NA
x
```

Comment: That is it! Thank you, I should study tidyverse deeper.

Comment: `pivot_wider()` is a particularly powerful function - especially the `values_fn=` attribute. PS Here is a bonus base R method `xtabs(value ~ pop_1 + pop_2, data=df, na.action=NULL)`

Comment: I've checked `pivot_wider()` solution more carefully and found out that ZAB is missing. Additional population value with NA should be added before its first mention, but this is another story.

Comment: Yes, Because the data doesn't have that in it, and we are dealing with a triangle of a matrix. I added a row of `AL, AL, NA` at the beginning of the data, and it needs `ZAB, ZAB, NA` at the end. That how the data is. Here is an idea, bind the data with a flipped data (df[c(2,1,3)] effectively), that would make a more matrix like dataset (still no diagonal). you could always drop part of the matrix later with the `upper.tri()` or `lower.tri()`. See edit

Answer (score 1):

Create a vector of all the unique values in the pop_1 and pop_2 columns of the data frame. This will be the names of the rows and columns of the matrix.

```
populations <- unique(c(table$pop_1, table$pop_2))
```

Create an empty matrix with the same number of rows and columns as the vector from step 1, using the matrix function. Set the default value of the matrix to NA using the value argument.

```
matrix <- matrix(NA, nrow = length(populations), ncol = length(populations))
```

Use the rownames and colnames functions to set the names of the rows and columns of the matrix to the values in the populations vector.

```
rownames(matrix) <- populations
colnames(matrix) <- populations
```

Use a for loop to iterate over the rows of the data frame. For each row, use the pop_1 and pop_2 columns to find the corresponding cells in the matrix, and use the value column to set the value of those cells.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(table)) {
  row_name <- table[i, "pop_1"]
  col_name <- table[i, "pop_2"]
  value <- table[i, "value"]
  matrix[row_name, col_name] <- value
}
```

After these steps, the matrix should be an asymmetric matrix with the values from the data frame in the appropriate cells, and NA in all the other cells.

When you look at the results of matrix:

```
       AL     ALT      BU     IRK      KK     KYA      TU     ZAB
AL  NA 0.43447 0.15267 0.25912 0.10435 0.19238 0.19186 0.18155
ALT NA      NA 0.34969 0.07506 0.29206 0.13597 0.46354 0.17870
BU  NA      NA      NA 0.18658 0.02297 0.08851 0.18950 0.05176
IRK NA      NA      NA      NA 0.12086 0.02690 0.29669 0.05551
KK  NA      NA      NA      NA      NA 0.04910 0.15779 0.03276
KYA NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA 0.23422 0.00568
TU  NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA 0.22181
ZAB NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
```

Comment: I hoped there was an easier solution but this one works well.

Comment: There might be simpler approaches with using library functions but I am not aware of that